# Domain for Multiple Companies

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

Hope all is well with everyone.

We would like to inquire the best practice on creating domains for multiple companies under one Parent company as we are a group of companies.

From our research we found that we need to create a separate domain for each company and all domains will be under in the same forest.

Waiting for feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forest is a security boundary. A domain is a management boundary. With modern delegation, fine-grained password policies, and item-level targeting in GPO, its entirely possible to create management boundaries within a single domain as well.

There's no "right" answer. Evaluate your situation and choose whichever is most appropriate based on your regulatory, security, and management needs.

Comment: MDMarra, Thanks for the response.  We would like to have SSO facility depending on the domain the user is logged on from.  Easy management for security roles as more or less the rules will be same for all the companies.  We want single point of control - not to login to each domain to make changes. Based on this - what would be your suggestion.

Comment: @Eng.Ya553r this is not a decision you should be making based on the free advice of strangers on the Internet. You're essentially asking "How do I architect my identity store for a multi-tenant organization?" This is not a quick question to answer, as I tried (and apparently failed) to explain above. If you or your staff are not qualified to do this on your own, please look to hire consultants that do this day in and day out. Once you've implemented an AD structure, it is *very hard* to says "whoops" and start over.